# Running a terminal-type command in my application

Tags: application-development, quickly

I want to create an Ubuntu Application which has a GUI for a CLI-application. I want to run a terminal command, for example, on a button click in my application. How can I do this? Or should I really not being doing this?

Can I also grab what would be displayed as the last/current line when running the terminal command?

*(I am writing my app using Quickly as described [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python (the programming language the desktop Quickly template uses) provides the subprocessing module for calling other programs. The documentation is here: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

It provides convenience functions, but for the more advanced stuff (like reading the output as you described if I recall correctly) you often need to use its Popen class.